# libreoffice exits immediately - on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: libreoffice

I just found that my libreoffice on Linux just exited on startup - with no help.
I tested it running as another user - and it worked fine for other users.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it turned out to be this file

```
/tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_129c53f29259157d5884d6e030f7846b
```

I had to delete, for it to startup properly.
I also tried removing

```
 ~/.config/libreoffice
```

but that did not change anything.

So a question - with a fix - if someone should hit this problem (I didn't find a good answer :)